# Can't access DOM elements in React Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am making an application with a table where the rows expand when clicked on. I have implemented the expansion of rows already (I am using a very similar idea as this [link](https://gist.github.com/markerikson/bd9f03e0808558c5951e02f1aa98c563)).

Based on the referred link above, in the expanded rows (under line 43), I want to add a `<div>` element with `id={item.id}`. Then just before we exit the if block, I want to send that `<div>` element I just made with `id={item.id}` to an external method (eg. an external API).

Right now, I am trying to do `document.getElementById(item.id)` but it returns `undefined`. I also tried using refs, but was getting the same problem.

The thing is, if I move the `<div>` element to let's say the render method, everything works fine. It's just here that I'm having troubles accessing the DOM element.

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n5u2wwjg/101051/

Comment: Well, first off, one's not meant to access and manipulate the DOM like that from a React component. You're supposed to update the state (usually through `setState`), write the render function that depends on that state, then let React handle the DOM updates for you. Second, what the issue may be depends on where that `getElementById` call is, how you're using refs, and so on, so it'd be helpful to show your own not-working code

Comment: @kingdaro I know we're not supposed to manipulate the DOM like that in React, but it's necessary to access that DOM element since I'm using an external Web API that requires the particular DOM element.
Here is a JSFiddle of my (not-working) code: https://jsfiddle.net/n5u2wwjg/101051/

Answer (score 0):

Use React's [refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) to capture the DOM element, and access that DOM in componentDidMount(). The DOM you're referring to in render() method is React's virtual DOM, and at the time render method was called first time, it's not actually display on the browser yet, that's why document.getElementById return undefined